# How can i use sjoin to merge two GeoDataFrames without an error

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I am attempting to complete a spatial join between two GeodataFrames but this error comes up:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat.
```

This is my code/plan which got me to that error;

The two dataframes are named `tag_df` and `cpr_df` which contain Latitude and Longitude values so I firstly created a geodataframe for both;

```
tag_df['coordinates']=list(zip(tag_df.Longitude,tag_df.Latitude))
tag_df['coordinates']=tag_df['coordinates'].apply(Point)
tag_gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(tag_df,geometry='coordinates',crs={'init' :'epsg:4326'})

cpr_df['coordinates']=list(zip(cpr_df.sample_longitude_decimal,cpr_df.sample_latitude_decimal))
cpr_df['coordinates']=cpr_df['coordinates'].apply(Point)
cpr_gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(cpr_df,geometry='coordinates',crs={'init' :'epsg:4326'})
```

I then created a 5 nautical mile buffer for `cpr_gdf`:

```
cpr_gdf['p_buffer']=cpr_gdf['coordinates'].buffer(5*(1/60))
```

I now want to do a spatial join to find which `tag_gdf` values are in which buffered `cpr_gdf` values;

```
tag_in_cpr=sjoin(tag_gdf,cpr_gdf,how='left',op='within')
```

Which comes up with this error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: The solution (for now) is to downgrade your pandas version from 0.23 to 0.22. The error is unfortunately introduced by a change in pandas 0.23.0.

Comment: But, given the bug report here: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/731, this error might also be masking the problem that no rows are actually matching. You can check if this is the case by using `how='inner'`

Comment: Hi after I used how='inner' i obtained an Empty GeoDataFrame. However, from knowledge of the files i know there are tag_gdf values within the cpr_gdf. I saw your fix on the link but i am not sure how to input it into my code?

Comment: Are you sure they are overlapping? (eg did you plot them?) One reason could be that both have a different coordinate reference system, geopandas does not automatically convert them to the same. If `how='inner'` gives an empty frame, that means that nothing is overlapping, and the fix I mentioned would not change that.

Comment: Hi my apologies the geopandas 0.22 does work thank you for this! .. but now the right df (cpr_gdf) has all nan values.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant above with that there are no rows matching. Your dataframes are apparently not overlapping. Did you plot them on the same figure to check that? Maybe they are in a different coordinate reference system?